# Powershell Outlook Integration

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell

I have Csv file holding lots of email addresses, I also have an html i need sending it by mail to all those people.
I must do it from my outlook but i cannot go one by one.
I know powershell has send-mailmessage option but i need them to go out from my outlook, and i know i can go manualy add all the recipient at one time but here is the thing:
I need to create automation for someone, using powershell that on one click the script will take recipients from csv, take the html and WILL USE OUTLOOK to combine it and send it.
i googled it and couldnt find solution, has anyone done something like that if thats possible?

Comment: You will need to use the "outlook interop" assembly. (that is what you should search to find the most relevant results with powershell. This guide ( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/outlook-email-automation-with-powershell/ ) has an example that can be modified

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, you could also try to post a thread in [Outlook for developer forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=outlookdev&brandIgnore=True&sort=relevancedesc&category=&forum=outlookdev&filter=&sort=relevancedesc&brandIgnore=true&searchTerm=), where there are many outlook development experts and you may get more help about powershell Outlook Intergration.